how to create this Mercedes star texture?
I tried to find/create this texture but failed, can you show me how can I make this texture, or if you found this online can you please share it with me?


Update: I am using a tile image but it does not sit right.



Hello, maybe simply create this pattern with an image editor like Photoshop or Krita then blur it a bit and use the result in an Image Texture node that you plug into a Bump node that you plug into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF

I agree with @moonboots here, if you want this as texture this probably very easy to create in image editing software and not really a question for the use of Blender. Unless your question was how to get this texture onto your model.

Easy, but where is the fun then(as opposed to procedural texture)? :D But, joking aside, one can also use Blender to actually make things easier. You can model the geometry and then render a depth map or a normal map. It might be quite convenient at times since Blender has many useful features like randomize transforms if you use multiple objects and Geometry Nodes for scattering and randomizing patterns and you don't usually have similar tools in image editors at least not with so much control. Blender is a really good tool on its own for creating patterns a lot more complex than this...

The easy way
The easy way would be to just model the geometry of the star and use a couple of Array modifiers to repeat it:

I also use bevel modifier there to round the corners a bit, because it cannot be sharp when made out of plastic like your reference. Then just render it from above with an orthographic camera to get a depth or normal map. No need to worry about materials or anything(even though I did set them to flat emission shaders just to render faster since I don't really care what the material is), just make sure you have Z, or Mist or Normal passes enabled:

I would use Cycles for this since it renders very quickly in any case. It should be possible to use EEVEE as well, but Cycles tends to be more precise and since it doesn't need many samples and renders really fast anyway, it doesn't matter much. I used 128 samples without any really good reason, just felt like that's definitely more than enough.
To increase precision you should adjust the camera clipping values to match the range your geometry occupies in relation to camera:

If you render to a Multilayer EXR file, you can then access the depth and normal information with the compositor:

Or you could just save the result of this with compositing during rendering with File Output node. I recommend using EXR format, but that's just a recommendation and you could use anything, just remember that normal and depth information is non-color data so you have to set image color space to it later when using the textures in your material. It's OK to leave EXR's default Linear REC 709 since that's pretty much the same thing, unless you feel like semantic meaning of setting it to non-color will let you sleep better.
You could then cut out the repeating part in the Compositor. You can use Crop node in Blender 4.2 and use Translate Node with wrapping in both axes enabled and image translated half way up and to the side to bring the seam to the middle, so you see what you are doing:

At this point you might notice how important it was to find the correct Array modifier values so that the logo is repeated exactly along XY coordinates and doesn't drift up or down like in my case:

But I'll just ignore it for now. Since we repeat only one segment, the resolution can be absolutely insane(as for this purpose) anyway and defects like this will not be visible anyway. It would actually make sense to reduce the resolution to save memory.
Then it's just a matter of using the normal or depth map in your material, adjusting the aspect ratio of the mapping since the image we got was not square and tweaking other stuff:


I'd like to add the fun way with procedural texture later, but I am just not feeling like I need that much fun at the moment. :D

I did assume general knowledge of modelling and how to use the Compositor and skipped a lot of stuff, so if any of this is not clear, just let me know and I'll edit the answer to add more detail.

Thanks for the answer, I'll try that and let you know.

Hi, I have tried to make it by using your method but I am not getting the part where you showed the repetition of the image to composite, I have got the image but don't know how to repeat it and then use it in the material. So if you can please elaborate on that part, thanks.

Well, the repetition is done with geometry - the array modifiers, you should have repetition in the image in the first place and compositor is used to just crop the repeating part so that it's tilable and it's repeated in the material by default, it's not repeated in the compositor. You don't want to store repeating information in your textures as that would just be a waste or memory.

You should only need the compositor nodes I show in the screenshots to crop the rendered image.

I have already made the tile image but when I use it in the material it is not working as it is supposed to, I don't know how to attach photos to the comment otherwise I would have done it to explain better

I am editing the question and attaching the latest photos of the shader tab and UV editing tab

It simply needs to be "tilable" or "seamless". This means the edges of your image need to match so when it's repeated, the pattern repeats without seams. In order to match the pattern on the image you need to crop it in the right way that I have described in the answer above. Where the image ends at the right side it needs to match on the left side and where it ends at the bottom it needs to match at the top. Not sure how to explain it any better, but it's a basic concept in texturing that you should definitely understand - search for the terms online and you should find plenty examples.

Maybe it's spelled "tileable" - sorry, English is not my first language and it's a term that is often spelled both ways online, so I don't know which is correct. Maybe "tileable" is the correct one. :D Sorry. My autocorrect seems not to know the word :D

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thanks man, I have got it.
